# Why can't I make 2 paths point to the same file twice in require.js?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'd like to have 2 requirejs paths pointing to the same module:

```
var require = {
    paths: {
        "hardPath" : "file",
        "alias" : "file"
    }
}
```

When I run my app I get a load timeout error for "alias". If my app's js files only reference one of "hardPath" or "alias" but not the other, it works fine. But if I have js files that reference both of these, I get the load timeout. Is there some reason that require.js does not allow this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API that RequireJS uses for this is [map](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-map). You can configure it such that when any of your modules request 'alias' they are automatically given 'hardPath':

```
require.config({
    // paths, shim, etc.

    // and now remap requests for the wrong module name to the right one
    map: {
        '*': {
            'alias': 'hardPath'
        }
    }
});
```

From the doc linked above:

> In addition, the paths config is only for setting up root paths for module IDs, not for mapping one module ID to another one.